# Download a file from SharePoint with modern authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, azure-functions, power-automate

I have an Azure Function that downloads a document from SharePoint.

```
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        ICredentials credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, secureString);



        webUrl = webUrl.EndsWith("/") ? webUrl.Substring(0, webUrl.Length - 1) : webUrl;
        string webRelativeUrl = null;
        if (webUrl.Split('/').Length > 3)
        {
            webRelativeUrl = "/" + webUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, 4)[3];
        }
        else
        {
            webRelativeUrl = "";
        }

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.Credentials = credentials;
            byte[] data;
            try
            {
                Uri endpointUri = new Uri(webUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + webRelativeUrl + path + "')/$value");

                data = client.DownloadData(endpointUri);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                
            }


        }
```

now on `client.DownloadData(endpointUri)` I receive the InnerException `cannot contact web site or the web site does not support sharepoint online credentials`.

After some research I came to the conclusion that I use an 'Legacy Authentication methode'. Re-enabling the legacy authentication is not an option.

As I understand it I have to use the 'Modern Authentication'.

Now my question is: How can I download/upload files from SharePoint with Modern Authentication through Azure Function?

side note: My Azure Function get's triggered via HTTP Post in Power Automate.

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint Online credentials - is equivalent of having the users himself logging in with his password  without him being present(by hardcoding the username and password). If Legacy Authentication method is blocked ( for security reasons ) - then an interaction from the user is required for going through the authentication and obtain the token for subsequent action.

Since you are using the Azure Function - retrieving the token necessary to download the file(s) from the Sharepoint with interaction is not possible.

To over come this, you could make use of the Sharepoint App Only Access to download.

This bypass the requirement of the user/user's credentials in order to access the file/download the file.You will be getting authenticated using the Client Secret and Client ID. You could also restrict the permission that the APP has.

You could refer to this :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Alternatively you could use - App only Graph permission to read the file content.

Comment: Thank you. What I don`t quite understand is: Im using PnP.Framework to use this: 'var cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]")'. I still have to set cc.Credentials to use 'File.OpenBinaryDirect()' to download a file from SharePoint. Why do I need Credentials? (I have yet to test if a download works if the account from Credentials uses MFA)

Comment: cc here stands for the client cred. It is not related to the user's credentials :) the authentication happens at the app level (not at users) - the MFA is not subjected to app.